# Does adal4j-1.6.2.jar supported by Java 11 or not

Tags: jar

I am going to use the following jar in development of a product:

adal4j-1.6.2.jar

I am using java 11 for product development.

I just want to confirm, whether above mentioned jar is supported in JAVA 11 or not.

Thanks,
Ravi

Searched for Jar support on google

Answer (score 1):

MSAL4J, which is the new client MS Identity client library for Java, and has all ADAL4J features and more, does support Java 11. You can get find it on [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java)